# How does a Muslim pray in a non-Muslim environment?

Tags: salat, interfaith

In an environment (house) where the woman is of a Christian faith (Catholic) and has crosses around the premises, how can a Muslim man perform his salat's? Is this allowed? Or is the Muslim prohibited from praying in such an area?

May Allah SWT guide us all. Ameen.

Comment: Corollary question: can a muslim husband allow his wife to decorate the home with idols?

Comment: Not sure I follow? - they are just crosses with no idols on them

Comment: Honestly i live in a deep catholic region  but crosses in houses seem to me an exception so your scenario is far away from reality. Maybe a cross on the wall in some room is more realistic.

Comment: An idol in islam isn't just a figure of a god being worshiped, it's any object that is worshiped or represents something that is worshiped other than allah. I was always under the impression a cross qualifies as an idol, whether there is a sculpture of jesus on it or not.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - the spouse has lots of crosses around her property. So I am just concerned if I would be living in sin and if I can still practice my faith.

Comment: In that case it is better to have your own house in any case it's the most appropriat way in the view of most scholars not to live dependent on your wife.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - so we cannot live together even though she is of the book and practices her faith?

Comment: No what i mean is: the man in islam is in charge of his wife and family. The solution to stay together in such a situation is to have at least one special room. However many scholars on fatwa sites would support the idea of imposing yourself your relugious views etc. on your non-Muslim wife.

Comment: Makes sense. We wont get a place together until something comes up - could be a couple of months or such. in the meantime i have stayed for 4 days with her and was just concerned about my faith. I don't want Allah SWT to be angry at me because I am in such an environment. No doubt in the new place, i will have my office room which will also be my prayer room. But i fear Allah SWT in case I misunderstood something about marrying into an interfaith scenario but still allowing her to practice.

Answer (score 3):

> In an environment (house) where the woman is of a Christian faith
>   (Catholic) and has crosses around the premises, how can a Muslim man
>   perform his salat's? Is this allowed?

Yes, it is. That is why it is permissible to marry people of the book. You should pray just like you pray in normal circumstances.